# Purpose of 就...了 in 这套房子下午就没有阳光了吧？

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure

The conversation is:

> ```
> A: 这套房子下午就没有阳光了吧？
> B: 是的。
> ```

Can you guys tell me the purpose of 就...了 in that question? Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can see component in your sentence 下午就没有阳光了(There has been no sunlight on afternoon) as [particular situation]就[other situation]. It denote [other situation] occurred after [particular situation]. In this component [particular situation] is 下午 and [other situation] is 没有阳光了. So 没有阳光了 occurred after 下午 has begun.

You can see component in your sentence 没有阳光了(There has been no sunlight) as [situation]了. It denote [situation] has happened. In this component [situation] is 没有阳光 so 没有阳光 has happened.

Answer (score 1):

An extension of 一 A 就 B  is that you can omit 一 and replace A as a condition.

一到下午就没有阳光了 Can be rephrased as
下午就没有阳光了

了follows 没有阳光, expressing the shift of situation has happened. It  has sunshine before noon, in other words.